# AWS SDK PHP .aws/credentials configuration

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, aws-php-sdk

I have a web application that I have built and using AWS SDK PHP and currently I pull all of my credentials in from an external config file located from within /etc/aws/creds.php (returns a php array of param values).  This works just fine with the default php.ini settings (being loose and open).  As I begin locking things down I am struggling with this error:

PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Aws\Common\Exception
InstanceProfileCredentialsException' with message 'Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server. When you are not running inside of Amazon EC2, you must provide your AWS access key ID and secret access key in the "key" and "secret" options when creating a client or provide an instantiated Aws\Common\Credentials
CredentialsInterface object.

This gets picked up in /var/log/httpd/error_log.  The documentation on AWS SDK API says I have to use an .aws/credentials file for the given user.  Well my user is http (for apache) and its home directory is /srv/http/.  I cannot effectively put the credentials in that file as it would be publicly available to anyone on my site.

The question I have is how do I change the location for this credentials file?  I need to change the location to the credentials file just so I can resolve the error, just so I can tighten up php.ini display_errors = Off so my scripts will work properly and securely. (NOTE: I know that single php.ini change isn't the holy grail to security its just the one thing hanging up my ability to entirely lock down my php.ini config).

Comment: Already checked here? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/credentials.html#using-the-aws-credentials-file-and-credential-profiles

Comment: From what I see there I cannot really use any of the options.  1) Im not looking to use a credentials file at all, my web application has multiple AWS accounts for various roles (about 13 of them).  2) While the credentials file does support multiple AWS credentials I already have my entire application written around external .php credential files housed in /etc/aws/. 3) I am only trying to figure out how to appease this PHP Fatal Error: so i can lock down my php.ini settings.  Seems strange this error requires me to use a credentials file in order to appease it.

Comment: A better way to ask this question: "What is the proper way to use AWS SDK PHP credentials with Apache when the service runs as user http:http and its home directory is the web root?  You cannot use a /srv/http/.aws/credentials file for that user as its publicly exposed via your website"

Comment: I here you: I had my problems with webapp and root users.... Did you try adding to the credential file reading permissions only to the Apache user (or group, I think is www-data)?